# How to split file in hdfs with HIVE

Tags: hive, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I need to split files under the hive table to file no more than 100mb with `create 
table as select`

I tried split with `mapred.max.split.size` but it did not help me.

Comment: Why? ............

Comment: i need to upload my files(data) into mq queue with storage handler. and i have 100mb limits in queue .